# Fill array gaps with underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Using underscorejs, how can I fill gaps in an array. Eg:

```
fillGaps([1,2,3,6,7,22,23,24]) => [1,2,3,'...',6,7,'...',22,23,24]
```

Comment: I don't think underscore adds anything useful to solve this. Simply iterate over the array and compare.

Comment: I imagined you could do something smart by partitioning and then joining, or the like. But no.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it:

```
function fillGaps(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 2; i > -1; i--) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1] - 1) {
            arr.splice(i+1, 0, '...');
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This modifies the array in place.

Alternatively:

```
function fillGaps(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1] - 1) {
            result.push('...');
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or if you want to make your code less readable and abuse `.reduce` and the comma operator:

```
function fillGaps(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(result, v, i, arr) {
        return result.push(v), v < arr[i+1] - 1 ? result.push('...') : false, result;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function fillGaps(arr) {
  var result = [];
  var previous = 0;
  _.each(arr, function(p) {
    if (p > previous + 1) {
      result.push('...')
    }
    result.push(p);
    previous = p;
  });
  return result;
}
```

But I'm sure there is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(fillGaps([1,2,3,6,7,22,23,24]));

function fillGaps(arr) {
    var l=arr.length;
    var out=[];
    var thisel;
    var lastel=null;
    for(var i=0;i<l;i++) {
        thisel=arr[i];
        if(lastel!=null && thisel>lastel+1) out.push("...");
        out.push(thisel);
        lastel=thisel;
    }
    return out;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5y9gzae9/1/)

You can remove `lastel!=null &&` and set `var lastel=1;` at the beginning if you want `fillGaps([3,6,7,22])` to return `['...',3,'...',6,7,'...',22]` (also filling the first place if not 1)

Answer (score 0):

Use inArray method to find missing element in the array. Here [._last()](http://underscorejs.org/#last) will return last element in the array.

```
var array1 = [1,2,4,7];
var array2 = [];
for(var i = 0;j < _.last(array1) ; i++){
   if($.inArray(i+1, array1)>=0) 
      array2[i]= i+1; 
   else array2[i]="..";
}
```

Comment: With the help of array length last element will be captured like this. `array1[array1.length-1]`